# To_Date is giving me ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

Sample Value of **LOGOUT** column from the table : 2021-07-08 14:57:34.000

I am having the below SQL server query as part of my sql script and it is working fine.

```
 MAX(ISNULL(LOGOUT, '2999-12-31')) AS MAX_LOGOUT
```

i have converted this line of query in to oracle as below

```
 MAX(NVL(LOGOUT, TO_DATE('2999-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))
          ) AS MAXLOGOUT
```

I am getting the error ***ORA-01722: invalid number. How to fix this error***

Comment: `NVL()` needs a second argument

Comment: That is what "TO_DATE('2999-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD')"

Comment: If LOGOUT is null then i am using the second parameter with TO_DATE

Comment: What is the datatype of `LOGOUT`? You may also use shorter and more readable `date '2999-12-31'` date literal

Comment: LOGOUT is DATE datatype.

Comment: Please, provide reproducible example. DDL and insert statements for sample data

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from that column expression; and that is actually what you have - you didn't use `to_char()` instead of `to_date()`, naybe?

Comment: You say that the data type of LOGOUT is `date`, but you show a sample value with decimal places for seconds. Such a thing does not exist in Oracle. Either you are adding those .000 yourself (they are not displayed in any place in Oracle like that), or the data type is `timestamp` rather than `date`. Please clarify.

Comment: Please, provide the result of `select dump(max(LOGOUT)) from your_table`. As pointed earlier, `date` has no fractional seconds in any display format

Comment: Your query works without errors [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4f9e8d96ba3bac19f1823f3e7d68494c). Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with a complete query (including `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for you table and data) that replicates the error.

Comment: @MT0 Thank you. I just added the date format to 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS' and it works for me. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the value of LOGOUT?

This work's fine for me:

```
SELECT MAX(NVL(SYSDATE, TO_DATE('2999-12-31', 'YYYY-MM-DD'))) AS maxlogout FROM dual
```

Result:

> 21/07/2021 17:24:06

Comment: The sample value of LOGOUT is 2021-07-08 14:57:34.000.

Answer (score -1):

MAX(NVL(LOGOUT, TO_DATE('2999-12-31 14:46:13', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))) AS MAXLOGOUT

Comment: Nope. `to_date('2999-12-31', 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` gives *ORA-01861: literal does not match format string*, because it doesn't. Also, date literals are written like `date '2999-12-31'`.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I understand now. I apologize for the mistake in the earlier comments. Now I have accepted the correct answer from Burno.